# Comparing time object with literal string in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to compare the current time with a value given as text string. I don't know how to bring things to a common denominator, because I feel that the time obtained is not quite the same as a simple text string, even if it looks so when printing.

Test code:

```
import time
import datetime

def GetTimeAndWeekday(data):
  datetime_now = datetime.datetime.now()
  if data == "hms":
    time_now = datetime.time(datetime_now.hour, datetime_now.minute, datetime_now.second)
    return time_now
  elif data == "hm":
    time_now = datetime.time(datetime_now.hour, datetime_now.minute)
    return time_now
  return datetime_now

data = "hm"
found = GetTimeAndWeekday(data)
print found  # for "hm" this gives current time in HH:MM:00 format, say 05:29:00

# I want to do something like this logic:
if found == "05:29:00":
  print "the same"
else:
  print "not the same"
```

How can I do that logic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [strftime()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

```
if found.strftime('%I:%M:%S') == "05:29:00":
    print 'the same'
else:
    print 'not the same'
```